# What's the Bracha Rishona on oatmeal/oat flakes with cold milk?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, dairy

What's the Bracha Rishona on oatmeal/oat flakes with cold milk? Is it Pri Adama or Mezonot?
Do we need extra Sheakol on milk?

Comment: How do you know it isn't shehakol because no one eats it that way?

Comment: some do eat. and may be i would, if i knew the brocha :)

Comment: I mean it's not the normal method of consumption

Comment: if we search in google for images of muesli we find many examples. Mostly of times it mixed with nuts or/and fruits, but the main ingrediend is still oatmeal/oat flakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was asked to edit to the simplest version and post a source...

**TL:DR** In order for a grain to become “mezonot,” the kernels must either:

1. be broken (even partially)and then cooked.
2. lose their form completely as a result of cooking.
3. have the outer shell (bran) removed, and the grains stick together a little as a result of cooking.

Mishnah Berurah 208:6,15

*Look through my prior edits for the full answer.*

Comment: Reddit_Rabbi, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this detailed answer! I think that the question was specifically about flakes, so this answer would work better if [edit]ed to focus in that direction. Also, the answer will be much more valuable if it cites some sources for it Halachic assertions. I hope you'll look around and find other material here that's to your taste, perhaps including  our 368 other [tag:blessing] questions.

Answer (score -1):

[Per the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/cons-appr-cereal.htm), the blessings on **All-Bran Complete Oat Bran Flakes** are *Mezonos* and *Al Hamichya*.

Comment: I don't think that's the same food...

Comment: thanks, but there it's not clear, whether bracha is mesonot, when it is eaten cooked or also when it is eaten raw with milk.